# Elegant handling a dot-source failure in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I have a script that is using dot-sourcing

```
$Dependencies = "Script1","Script2","Script3"
$Dependencies | % { . ".\$( $_ ).ps1" }
```

I have tried to use a `Try { } Catch { }` which caught the error but that imported the script into the scope of the try and catch.

What is the cleanest way of detecting a failure of the dot-source import?

Usually I can set the `ErrorAction` to be `Stop` and that forces a function to throw an error but I don't seem to be able to do that with dot-sourcing.

**UPDATE**

In the end it turned out that try and catch did work. Here is my modified script

```
$Dependencies = "Script1","Script2","Script3"
$Dependencies |
    ForEach-Object {
        Try { . ".\$( $_ ).ps1" } 
        Catch { Throw }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet you used try-catch incorrectly. Take a look at following snippet (expanded for simplicity):

```
$Dependencies = "Script1","Script2","Script3"
$Dependencies | % {
    try {
        $psFile = ".\$($_).ps1"
        . $psFile
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to execute $psFile"
    }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have no idea how I managed to do that.